# Is there a way to pipe user input within a bash script into the cat command and have it save at a destination of my choosing as a text file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, cat

Something similar to this maybe:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo What is your name?
read name | cat > ~/Documents/file.txt
  if [[ $name==Bob ]]
echo something
fi
```

The command creates an empty file on manjaro mint.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `read` doesn't create any output.

And you have a syntax error further down the line, it would be a good idea to put your script(s) through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

```
#! /bin/bash
echo What is your name?
read -r name
echo "$name" > ~/Documents/file.txt
if [[ "$name" == "Bob" ]]; then
    echo something
fi
```

Comment: I was trying to do it without echo. But it looks like the only way. Spellcheck is cool. I didn't know about it. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @JBV - there's no trivial way of getting the content of a shell variable into a pipe or redirect without the use of an `echo` ...  you might be able to pull the value of `name` out of `proc/PID/environ` somewhere/-how using `cat` ... have fun trying :)